# How to make the player appear and move in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make my player to appear on screen and move. I was able to do that without classes, but now I'm trying to create the object player and things started to go wrong. I've got the following code:

Player class:

```
Player.initialize = function() {
height = 167.5;
width = 100;
pos_x = 350;
pos_y = 400;
player_image = new Image();
player_image.src = 'img/player_car_img.png';
};
```

The Game initialization:

```
Game.initialize = function() {
  this.entities = [];
  this.context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  player = new Player();
  player.initialize();

  //Road background
  road = new Image();
  road.src = 'img/road.png';
  rw = 800;
  rh = 600;

};
```

And then the drawing function:

```
Game.draw = function() {
  this.context.drawImage(road, 0,0, rw, rh);
  this.player.drawImage(player_image, pos_x, pos_y, width, height);
  this.player.pos_x += 1;
  this.player.pos_y += 1;
};
```

I'm new to Javascript, so I don't really know what I'm doing specially when it comes to objected-oriented programming in this. Anything helps.

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: There are no connections between the different parts of the code. Where is `this.player.drawImage` declared? Show the errors.

Comment: They are all together in the same file, and for some reason Eclipse isn't showing errors.

Comment: I can't run it on Eclipse, because it's a HTML file. If I can run it, I'm not sure how.

Comment: Is it missing a constructor?

Comment: @CarlosMenzoni Just to let you know, you're on the right track. You've come a long way from when you made your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript uses `prototype` to inherit functions from a "class" function.

Generally the format is to declare a constructor function (usually being uppercased), where `this` refers to the object that will be created.

```
function Game() {
  this.entities = [];
  this.context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  this.player = new Player();

  //Road background
  this.road = new Image();
  this.road.src = 'img/road.png';
  this.rw = 800;
  this.rh = 600;
}
```

And then declare "instance" functions on the `prototype`:

```
Game.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.context.drawImage(this.road, 0,0, this.rw, this.rh);
  this.context.drawImage(
      this.player.player_image,
      this.player.pos_x,
      this.player.pos_y,
      this.player.width,
      this.player.height
    );
  this.player.pos_x += 1;
  this.player.pos_y += 1;
};
```

And then they are called like this:

```
var game = new Game();
game.draw();
```

Now just do the same thing for `Player`:

```
function Player() {
  this.height = 167.5;
  this.width = 100;
  this.pos_x = 350;
  this.pos_y = 400;
  this.player_image = new Image();
  this.player_image.src = 'img/player_car_img.png';
}
```

Comment: Replace `player =  new Player()` with `this.player =  new Player()`

Comment: @SimoEndre You're right. I missed that in a lot of places.

Comment: Well, I was able to do all that, but now it won't recognize the drawImage function. I opened the developer tools and it says that drawImage is undefined. I created a Player.prototype.drawImage(), but I'm sure how to make it draw something.

Comment: Yes I did. 

Player.prototype.drawImage = function() {
 this.context.drawImage(player_image, pos_x, pos_y,  width, height);
};

I put context, but I'm pretty sure it only works for Game.

Comment: @CarlosMenzoni I don't think `Player` needs `drawImage`. The `Game` should be responsible for that.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. But how do I create an object player with an image attached to it? I created player_image, but I don't think that's how it works in javascript.

Comment: @CarlosMenzoni When you're programming using prototypes, any variable which you want to share with other functions needs to be set/accessed using `this`. It will look very similar to `road` in the `Game`.

Comment: This is the error: game.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

Comment: This is the line where the error happens:   this.context.drawImage(this.player.player_image, this.player.pos_x, this.player.pos_y, this.player.width, this.player.height);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118666/discussion-between-4castle-and-carlos-menzoni).